# Translation of “can't get enough of you”

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

I would like to know how to translate the expression:

> I can't get enough of you

in French.

Would a literal translation such as:

> Je ne peux pas avoir assez de toi.

work?

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context? I notice you don't use "never" or "just". Is that meant in an admirative way, as a compliment to a lover for instance?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: C'est une expression qui traduirait le fait qu'on aime être avec la personne.

Comment: To answer precisely your question, no your suggestion does not work. The answers below offer good translations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Je ne peux me lasser de toi" ou bien "je ne saurais me lasser de toi" est une traduction possible.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible one could be "je ne peux pas me passer de toi".

Answer (score 5):

The pretty lyrics of *[Je T'ai Dans La Peau](http://www.paroles.net/chimene-badi/paroles-je-t-ai-dans-la-peau)*(1) from Chimène Badi’s  *Live à l’Olympia* album contain three possible ways to capture what I think you’re trying to say (the song’s title itself [*I’ve got you under my skin*] would probably also work):

in verse 2 = ‘se passer de’ = "[je ne peux pas me passer de toi](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=je%20ne%20peux%20pas%20me%20passer%20de%20toi&langTot=fr-en)";

in verse 17 = "je n'ai (n'aurai/n'aurais) [jamais trop de toi](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=jamais%20trop%20de%20toi&langTot=fr-en)", which, although “trop” (too much) is used instead of “assez” (enough) is probably the most literal, but least idiomatic, equivalent of the English phrase;

and in verse 22 = ‘[se lasser de](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=ne%20me%20lasse%20pas&langTot=fr-en)’, which is Iside’s good answer.

*Je T'ai Dans La Peau* by Chimène Badi

> Tu es la musique
>   (2) Dont je ne peux me passer (can’t/couldn’t live without = "je ne peux (pas) me passer de toi")
>
> Les refrains hypnotiques
>   Qui me rendent folle à lier
>
> Tu es le
>   mensonge
>   Qui sent la vérité
>   Je ne veux pas
>   Mais je plonge
>   Même
>   si ça doit brûler
>
> Tu as tout pour plaire
>   Jusqu'au moindre défaut
>   Comment m'en défaire
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>
> C'est plus fort que moi
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>   Je ne pense qu'à ça
>   [17] Je n'ai jamais trop de toi  (never have too
>   much =  « Je n'ai jamais trop de toi »)
>
> Dans la peau
>   Un jour ça me perdra,
>   Me perdras

---

> Tu es le parfum
>
> [22] Dont je ne peux me lasser  (can/could never get tired of = « je
>   ne peux (pas) me lasser de toi »)
>   La douleur du venin
>   Qui laisse les jambes coupées
>
> Tu es le mirage
>   Où rien n'est jamais bon
>   Le dernier paysage
>   Où je perds la raison
>
> Tu as tout pour plaire
>   Jusqu'au moindre défaut
>   Sans toi c'est l'enfer
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>
> C'est plus fort que moi
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>   Je ne pense qu'à ça
>   Je n'ai jamais trop de toi dans la peau
>
> Un jour ça me perdra,
>   Me perdras

---

> Je t'ai dans la peau
>   C'est plus fort que moi
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>   Je ne pense qu'à ça
>
> Je ne me rappelle plus
>   Si j'étais quelqu'un avant
>   Tout ce que j'ai vécu
>   S'était en
>   t'attendant
>
> S'était en t'attendant
>   S'était en t'attendant
>
> Je t'ai dans la peau
>   Je n'ai jamais trop de toi dans la peau
>   Un jour ça me perdras, 
>   me perdras
>   Je t'ai dans la peau
>
> Je t'ai dans la peau
>   Je t'ai dans la peau

*(not to be confused with [Edith Piaf](http://www.ooltra.net/Lyrics.php?a=EdithPiaf&s=JeTAiDansLaPeau)’s song with the same title)

Answer (score 3):

Ma modeste proposition : De toi, je n'en ai jamais assez.